# Could not set a workspace style as layer's default style using REST API

Tags: geoserver, style, rest, workspace

I am posting this data to

**DATA_ONE**

```
{"layer": {
          "enabled": true,
          "defautStyle":{
                    "name": "My_Roads_Style",
                    "workspace": "My_Workspace"
                        }
          }
}
```

**DATA_TWO**

```
{"layer": {
          "enabled": true,
          "defautStyle":{
                    "name": "My_Roads_Style"
                        }
          }
}
```

**REST_URL**

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/My_Workspace/styles/?name=My_Roads_Style
```

I have POSTed REST_URL with DATA_ONE it is giving 403 error.
I have POSTed REST_URL with DATA_TWO it is giving 403 error.
In both the cases it is giving same error.
What is wrong with my approch ?

I am able to apply the same style which is there in workspace to layer from Geoserver web interface.

I have tried it with Geoserver v2.2 and v2.5.